# Styles won't apply to my table cell

Tags: css, html-table, haml

Each table row is filled with each event:

```
- @events.each do |event|
    %tr
      %td= event.name
      %td= event.description
      %td= event.date
```

I want to be able to alter the text-align of only one table cell (event.description), I want to do this with CSS, but if I try:

```
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This will do it for all cells, not just one. So I tried putting that one cell in a wrapper:

```
- @events.each do |event|
    %tr
      %td= event.name
      #wrapper
        %td= event.description
      %td= event.date
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: What does the compiled markup look like?  Seems like you've created an HTML problem with your HAML.

Comment: The sass tag was removed on purpose because your question has nothing to do with Sass (your Sass compiles to the expected CSS just fine).  Do not add it back in.

Comment: I was working in sass though... I wanted to know the answer in sass format.

Comment: But Sass had nothing to *do* with your problem.

Comment: Well yes, I realise now that I just needed to adjust my haml. Obviously before this I was unsure what the problem was. But like I said, I was working in sass hence why I wrote sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting it in a wrapper, simply give the <td> element the `#wrapper` tag.

```
%td#wrapper= event.description
```